# Proving $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff with final topology induced by a function $f$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, category-theory, separation-axioms

Consider a Hausdorff topological space $(X,\tau)$. Suppose $(X,\tilde{\tau})$ is the minimal normalization of $(X,{\tau})$, that is, for every given normal topology $\sigma$, where $\tau \subset \sigma$ we have $\tau \subset \tilde{\tau} \subset \sigma$.

Suppose $A\subsetneq X$ and $d$ is a metric function for $(X,\tilde{\tau})$. Let $f(-)=d(A,-):(X,\tau) \to \mathbb{R}$. Induce the final topology $\alpha$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is continuous, is the space $(\mathbb{R},\alpha)$ a Hausdorff space?

While I have stated my main problem, I am unsure about the existence of $\tilde{\tau}$ as the minimal normalization of $\tau$, in case there is a counterexample (which I would be grateful to hear about it), suppose that such $\tilde{\tau}$ exists.

As the problem itself does not seem related to category theory, here is a brief explanation:

If my assumption is correct and the mentioned space is indeed Hausdorff, one can use $f$ and $2f$ to show that for any function $g:Z \to (X,\tau)$ where $g(Z)=A$, when the image of $g$ is not dense in $X$, then $g$ is not epic. That is, in the category of Hausdorff spaces, epis are maps with dense image.

Comment: I doubt your minimal normalisation exists in general.

Comment: Yes I fear that as well (but there is no real harm to my main problem). What I want is to learn some usable techniques to prove similar propositions for final topologies. Assume the case where the minimal normalization exists.

Comment: The distance function $d(A,-)$ is continuous with respect to the Euclidean topology on the right side: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Distance_from_Point_to_Subset_is_Continuous_Function And thus $\alpha$ has to contain the Euclidean topology, in particular it is Hausdorff.

Comment: As I change back my topology to $\tau$, $d(A,-)$ is not a distance function any more. Moreover, $\alpha$ is coarser than Euclidean topology and if they are equal $\tau = \bar{\tau}$.

Comment: Ah, I see, $d(A,-)$ is from $\tau$, not $\tilde\tau$.

Comment: I would not be surprised if the assumption that $\tilde{\tau}$ exists and is metrizable implies that $\tau$ itself was already normal so $\tilde{\tau}=\tau$ and the question becomes trivial.  In any case, this is definitely *not* the way to prove that epis in the category of Hausdorff space have dense image, since there are definitely examples where $\tilde{\tau}$ is not metrizable (take $X$ to be any normal non-metrizable space).

Comment: It's also unclear why you are talking about a minimal normalization at all, if what you really want is for it to be metrizable.  (Actually, it seems like what you really want for your argument is for there to be some real-valued function $f$ which vanishes on $A$ and nowhere else.  This is *perfect* normality, which is intermediate between normality and metrizability.)

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks for the mention, I was not familiar with perfect normality. I will check to see if it can solve my problem. Explanation: I wanted "minimal" normalization because if the normalization can be too fine for my argument, in the sense that discreet space is too fine which causes $\alpha$ to be trivial topology.